# When sprayer is used, all water to sink (faucet and sprayer) shuts off, how to fix?

Tags: water, faucet, sink, kitchen-sink

Whenever the sprayer for our kitchen sink is used, the water will suddenly cut off (to both the sprayer and the faucet) and not come back on again for several minutes. This has been going on for several months now, but today when it happened, the water didn't come back on at all (it's been about half an hour). Does anyone have an idea about what might be causing this and how to fix it?
Note: I checked under the sink and everything looks normal but I'm not sure if that means anything, the faucet doesn't feel any easier/harder to turn off than normal, all other water fixtures in the house work fine

Answer (score 1):

Your sprayer unit is not designed to sit at full system pressure, so the faucet unit that it came with is specially designed to shunt water towards the sprayer hose and head only when the sprayer lever is pressed. The faucet itself has an integral diverter valve to perform this function, it sounds like yours is not working right.

All faucet brands use their own proprietary diverter mechanism, you will need to get a manual for your faucet to get it apart and replace the valve. It might look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Sometimes nonfunctional diverters just have pipe crud in them that you can brush out, or dissolve with vinegar.